# How to add count labels to faceted likert plot `ggstats::gglikert`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using `ggstats::gglikert` to create some likert plots. The function by default outputs percentages on each bar. I wanted to show the actual frequencies instead and I found a way using `annotate` to achieve this.

However, this method does not seem to work when I add facets to the plot. `gglikert` has a parameter `facet_rows` and I used it to facet by group. When I use `annotate` to add the frequencies the same way, I get an error message saying that aesthetics should be of length 1 or 60. But my `p2_df` actually has 30 rows and I'm wondering why I get this error? Is there a way to add frequencies to my faceted plots? I'm open to any solutions. Thank you!

##### sample data

```r
remotes::install_github("larmarange/ggstats")
library(ggstats)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

likert_levels <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "neutral", "agree", "strongly agree", NA)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  q1 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  q2 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  q3 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  group = sample(c("pre", "post"), 100, replace = TRUE)
) |> 
  mutate(across(-group, ~factor(.x, levels = setdiff(likert_levels, NA))),
         group = factor(group, levels = c("pre", "post")))
```

##### plot without facets

```
p <- gglikert(
  data = df,
  include = q1:q3,
  add_labels = FALSE
)

p_df <- layer_data(p)
p_df$correct_x <- (p_df$xmax + p_df$xmin) / 2
p + annotate(geom="text", x = p_df$correct_x, y = p_df$y, label = p_df$count)
```

[image]

##### plot with facet

```r
p2 <- gglikert(
  data = df,
  include = q1:q3,
  add_labels = FALSE,
  facet_rows = vars(group)
)

p2_df <- layer_data(p2)
p2_df$correct_x <- (p2_df$xmax + p2_df$xmin) / 2
p2 + annotate(geom="text", x = p2_df$correct_x, y = p2_df$y, label = p2_df$count)
```

```
Error in `annotate()`:
! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 3rd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (60)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `label`
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5.     └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
  6.       ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
  7.       │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
  8.       │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
  9.       │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 10.       │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 11.       │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 12.       └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13.         └─l$compute_geom_2(d)
 14.           └─ggplot2 (local) compute_geom_2(..., self = self)
 15.             └─self$geom$use_defaults(data, self$aes_params, modifiers)
 16.               └─ggplot2 (local) use_defaults(..., self = self)
 17.                 └─ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(params[aes_params], nrow(data))
```

---

**EDIT**

I was using `exclude_fill_values` parameter in `gglikert` to remove unwanted level in my plot; this messed up the positions of the count labels. However, based on @stefan's solution, passing in the same value for `exclude_fill_values` in `position_likert` resolved the issue.

##### updated data

```
likert_levels <- c("strongly disagree", "disagree", "neutral", "agree", "strongly agree", "do not know", NA)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(   
  q1 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),   
  q2 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),   
  q3 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),  
  group = sample(c("pre", "post"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9)) ) |>   
  mutate(across(-group, ~factor(.x, levels = setdiff(likert_levels, NA))),        
         group = factor(group, levels = c("pre", "post")))
```

##### plot

```
p <- gglikert(
  data = df,
  include = q1:q3,
  facet_rows = vars(group),
  add_labels = FALSE,
  exclude_fill_values = "do not know"
)

p +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label_number_abs(hide_below = 1)(after_stat(count))
    ),
    stat = StatProp,
    complete = "fill",
    position = position_likert(vjust = 0.5, exclude_fill_values = "do not know")
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a hacky approach using `layer_data` and `annotate` you could achieve your desired result more easily using a `geom_text` and `after_stat`. The code below is simply a modified and stripped down version of the code used by [`gglikert`](https://github.com/larmarange/ggstats/blob/1788587c27b5118b048039142f62265796666790/R/gglikert.R#L216-L235) to add the percentage labels under the hood. .

```r
library(ggstats)
library(ggplot2)

p <- gglikert(
  data = df,
  include = q1:q3,
  facet_rows = vars(group),
  add_labels = FALSE
)

p +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = label_number_abs()(after_stat(count))
    ),
    stat = StatProp,
    complete = "fill",
    position = position_likert(vjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for a great answer. My actual data contained some 0 counts in one one of the groups. Modifying the aesthetics to `aes(label = label_number_abs()(after_stat(if_else(count > 0, count, NA))))`removed the 0 counts.

Comment: updated data for reproducibility: `set.seed(123);
df <- data.frame(
  q1 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  q2 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  q3 = sample(likert_levels, 100, replace = TRUE),
  group = sample(c("pre", "post"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9))
) |> 
  mutate(across(-group, ~factor(.x, levels = setdiff(likert_levels, NA))),
         group = factor(group, levels = c("pre", "post")))`

Comment: The developer of the ggstats package already accounted for this case. Try  `label_number_abs(hide_below = 1)(after_stat(count))`. (: